# How to generate a multiplicative space vector in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to generate "automatically" a vector `0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 0.3, 1, 3, 10, 30` (in multiplicative space).

I know linspace and logspace functions, but I couldn't find any similar function for multiplicative space.

Is there any? Otherwise, how to generate a vector like the one I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way with `bsxfun`, also considering multiplication to smaller spaces:

```
x = [0.01,0.03,0.05]    % initial vector, works for various lengths
n = 12;                 % times it should get multiplied in rising direction
m = 3;                  % times it should get multiplied in falling direction

Z = bsxfun( @times, x(:), 10.^(-m:n) )
Z = Z(:)

% if preferred, bulky one-liner:
% Z = reshape( bsxfun( @times, x(:), 10.^(-m:n) ) , 1 , [])
```

---

I assumed a multiplication with the multiplication vector, e.g.:

```
10.^(0:n) =   1         10         100        1000       10000      100000  ....
```

But custom vectors `Y` are also possible:

```
Z = bsxfun( @times, x(:), Y(:)' ) Z = Z(:)
```

Comment: Why use `repmat`? Transpose `x` instead and let `bsxfun` handle the expansion: `Z = reshape(bsxfun(@times, x', 10.^(-m:n)), [], 1)`.

Comment: @erikced: that is indeed working nicely! I always underestimate the possibilities of bsxfun. Thanks! I'm not a big fan of bulky one-liners and I also considered it before. I included it now anyway.

Answer (score 3):

A function that might help you achieving this in a very easy and compact way is the Kronecker tensor product [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html).
You can use it to rewrite [thewaywewalk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21060536/2663841) as:

```
v = [0.01;0.03;0.05]; % initial vector
emin = -3;            % minimal exponent
emax = 12;            % maximal exponent

Z = kron(10.^(emin:emax)',v(:))
```

which should give you the exact same result.

Comment: good to know! +1! I added the colon `(:)` to ensure compatibility with both row and column vector inputs.

Answer (score 2):

not very efficient but this will generate what you want. `inputvec` is your initial vector `[0.01 0.03]` in this case, `multiplier` is `10`. length of the required string `n` is `8`. `n` should be a multiple of `nn` (length of the input vector)

```
function newvec=multispace(n,inputvec,multiplier)

nn=length(inputvec);

newvec=zeros(1,n);
newvec(1:nn)=inputvec;
for i=1:n/nn-1
    newvec(i*nn+1:(i+1)*nn)=(newvec((i-1)*nn+1:(i)*nn)).*multiplier;  
end

end
```